# Call Knockout Validation Extender on Button Click

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I've been reading many questions that ask how to call a knockout validation extender on a button click event.  But all the answers that come close to answering the question, involve workarounds using the knockout-validate library. I'm not using the knockout-validate library.  All I want to do is validate an input field on a button click event using the validation rules defined in a knockout extender.

For simplicity I'm going to use the required extender from the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) and apply it to a simple use case.  This use case takes an input and on a button click event does something with the value the user entered.  Or updates the view to show the validation message if no value was entered.

**Knockout Code:**

```
ko.extenders.required = function (target, overrideMessage) {
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    function validate(value) {
        target.hasError(value ? false : true);
        target.validationMessage(value ? "" : overrideMessage || 'Value required');
    }

    return target;
};

function MyViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.userInput = ko.observable().extend({ required: 'Please enter a value' });

    /**
     * Event handler for the button click event
     */
    self.processInput = function () {
        //Validate input field
        //How to call the validate function in the required extender?

        //If passes validation, do something with the input value
        doSomething(self.userInput());
    };
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<span data-bind="visible: userInput .hasError, text: userInput .validationMessage" class="text-red"></span>
<button data-bind="click: processInput ">Do Something</button>
```

How can I trigger the validation on the button click event and show the validation message if it doesn't pass validation?

Comment: if you want only to check if your input is empty, you can check it in your click binding like `if(!self.userInput())` .Also it is better to define `self` as `var self  =  this ;`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, but I used the required example just for simplicity.  In my actual code I want to do more involved validation rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you were looking at the example here - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

You can not call validate directly, but the subscribe watches the value and runs the validate function on change and updates an observable you can check - hasError.

```js
ko.extenders.required = function (target, overrideMessage) {
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    function validate(value) {
        target.hasError(value ? false : true);
        target.validationMessage(value ? "" : overrideMessage || 'Value required');
    }
    
    //initial validation
    validate(target());
 
    //validate whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(validate);
 
    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

function MyViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.userInput = ko.observable().extend({ required: 'Please enter a value' });

    /**
     * Event handler for the button click event
     */
    self.processInput = function () {
        if(self.userInput.hasError()){
          console.log('has error');
        }else{
          console.log('no error');
        }
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<span data-bind="visible: userInput .hasError, text: userInput .validationMessage" class="text-red"></span>
<button data-bind="click: processInput ">Do Something</button>
```